# How do I get rid of underline when typing commands in zsh?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I use `zsh` with `oh-my-zsh` and it almost suits my needs. However, there is one thing I cannot figure out, namely how do I get rid of an underline of some parts of commands I type? Please have a look at the following screenshot to get an idea of what I'm talking about.

[image]

Comment: If the underline goes away once you have completed typing the command, it's probably indicating that the currently typed part isn't a valid command/function etc.

Comment: The thing is I don't need this indicator.

Comment: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting/issues/573#issuecomment-434918934

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guess they found a solution. Please [visit](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting/issues/573):

> To get a similar effect like in bash, that is including the ..., try:
>
> %(4~|.../%3~|%~)

- There are some more details in the linked thread.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a syntax highlighter turned on. Probably this [one](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting). Since you have `antigen` installed, please have a look in your `~/.zshrc`. Remove the following lines:

```
# Syntax highlighting bundle.
antigen bundle zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting
```

Comment: It didn't help.

Comment: Did you re-login?

Comment: I did `source ~/.zshrc`.

Comment: To reload `zsh` settings I usually execute: `exec zsh` that works for me.